# Does the order of index creation matter

Tags: mysql, optimization, indexing

Assuming I have an index on two columns on foo table indexed on (x,y)

If I search it as `select * from foo where x=1 and y=2` or `select * from foo where y=2 and x=1`. Does it really matter on mysql.

Comment: Generally, in SQL (any variant), you're telling the engine *what you want*, **not** *how to do it*. It's the job of the optimizer to work out how best to perform the job. Since there's no *logical* difference between your two queries, they should end up being optimized the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer - no, it doesn't matter. MySQL will try to pick the best index to use regardless of whether the column appears first or second in your `WHERE` clause.

You can prove this by running an [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html) statement on each one to get more information about [how MySQL will execute the query](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html) - it should show that the same index is used in both cases.

---

If you're talking about the order the columns appear in the index - `(x,y)` vs `(y,x)`, it also doesn't matter in this case since you're selecting using both columns. If you sometimes select on just one of the columns though, that column should appear first in the index so MySQL can use the partial index to help optimize the query when only one value is provided.

Answer (score 0):

Thats is so useful on Postgre on query optmizing to some querys, but MySQL just ignore index order (ASC,DESC) I dont know which version gonna suport this.

'I thought' this is a workbench bug, but the wockbench team anwser me:

> Our manual, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-index.html,
>    says:
>
> "An index_col_name specification can end with ASC or DESC. These
>   keywords are permitted for future extensions for specifying ascending
>   or descending index value storage. Currently, they are parsed but
>   ignored; index values are always stored in ascending order."
>
> So, probably this is the reason for what you see in Workbench: it
>   allows to add that DESC option, but server itself ignores it.

Earlier comments can be viewed at http://bugs.mysql.com/65893